# Can I use a closure to transform a List into a Hashmap where even indexed elements are the key and odd indexed elements are the value?

Tags: groovy, web-scraping, closures

I've got a list that I want to group by 2s and put into a HashMap where the first element is the Key and the second element is the Value. Right now I'm doing it in a for loop as such:

```
    Elements dList = showDoc.select("div#details dl > *")
    for(int i = 0; i < dList.size(); i += 2) {
        Element dt = dList.get(i)
        Element dd = dList.get(i+1)

        elsMap.put(dt.text(),dd)
    }
```

I had a problem previously where I had a bunch of elements with the same class that I wanted to be able to access based on the text of part of the element and I had a colleague show me how to do so with a Closure:

`def elsMap = showDoc.select("div.info_item").collectEntries{ el -> [el.select('b').text(), el.select(".desc_item")] };`

I was wondering if there was a similar way to do solve this problem. I can't figure out how I'd get the closure to group by 2s.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this list guaranteed to have an even number of elements?

Comment: Well nothing is ever 100% guaranteed but it should.. The elements I have are children of a <dl> element on a page, so there should always be a <dt> that corresponds to a <dd>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work ([using `collate`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#collate%28int,%20boolean%29)):

```
elsMap = dList.collate( 2, false )
              .collectEntries { a, b -> [ a.text(), b ] }
```

Collate takes a list and groups it into smaller lists of size N.

Passing `false` as the second parameter drops any trailing entries that would not make a group of size N